# Получение ссылок href с веб-сайта с помощью модуля Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautiful-soup

Я пытаюсь получить ссылки href с этой страницы , в частности, ссылки на страницы соответствующих клубов. Мой текущий код выглядит следующим образом. Я не включил импорт. При необходимости я просто импортировал запросы и из bs4 импортировал BeautifulSoup:

```
rsoLink = "https://illinois.campuslabs.com/engage/organizations?query=badminton"
page = requests.get(rsoLink)
beautifulPage = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for link in beautifulPage.findAll("a"):
  print(link.get('href'))
```

Мой вывод пустой, что говорит о том, что программа не нашла ссылки. Когда я посмотрел на HTML-структуру страницы, теги «a» кажутся вложенными глубоко в структуру страницы (они находятся внутри элемента, который находится внутри другого элемента, который сам находится внутри другого элемента). Мой вопрос в том, как я тогда буду получать доступ к ссылкам; я должен пройти через все эти элементы?

Answer (score 1):

Данные, которые вы видите на странице, загружаются с помощью JavaScript с другого URL. Так beautifulsoup не видит. Для загрузки данных вы можете использовать следующий пример:

```
import json
import requests

url = (
    "https://illinois.campuslabs.com/engage/api/discovery/search/organizations"
)

params = {"top": "10", "filter": "", "query": "badminton", "skip": "0"}

data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for v in data["value"]:
    print(
        "{:<50} {}".format(
            v["Name"],
            "https://illinois.campuslabs.com/engage/organization/"
            + v["WebsiteKey"],
        )
    )
```